# Make a variable DAO.QueryDef be read in a Excel VBA Sub

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have a Dao.DataBase as a parameter that is passed through a sub?

```
Public Sub FillInData(InfoArray() As Variant, qdf2 As DAO.QueryDef, k As Integer, rec_set_fill1 As Recordset, rec_set_fill As Recordset, DataBase As DAO.DataBase, TheId As Long, Weekly_Working As Integer)
         With qdf2
```

The problem is that it gives me an error that item is not found in this collection, so im assuming that its not reading from the Dao.Database or something

Comment: Are you sure you've registered the right  DAO library? It works for me with DAO 3.51 but I get an error using DAO 3.6 - but that might just be my setup

Comment: I have made Set qdf = Dbse.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, SQL_query)  with the SQL_query as some string, but then this returns nothing in the FillInData Sub

Answer (score 0):

If you create using CreateQueryDef with a null string for the name, it isn't appended to the querydefs collection - hence "item not found in collection". Name it something and it should exist long enough to get passed.